# convert always connected to occasionally connected application

Tags: enterprise-library, microsoft-sync-framework, smartclient, syncservices, occasionallyconnected

I have an existing client-server 3-tier application with the following stack :

- Smart-Client (Win-Forms)
- IIS/ASP.NET
- Sql server

Some of the data is stored in Entity–attribute–value (EAV) model.
All primary keys are integer identity columns.
Database operations are mostly performed using Stored procedures.

I am tasked with converting this application into an occasionally connected application (OCA)

There should be no issues with installation and resources limitation on the clients.

This is the first such project for me.

I have done some reading about

- [ms sync framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992)
- [Enterprise library / occasionally connected smart clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650163.aspx)
- SQL server replication

In order preserve existing code and limiting change impact, I am considering installing the the 3-tier application on each client , using sync framework to handle synchronization on the WS to handle synchronization. Also having one master server to which synchronizations will refer.

Does this solution look feasible?

Are there any other resources regarding converting an on always Connected 3-tier application to an occasionally connected application ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be feasible. not much change in your app. you just have to install a local database on your clients.

however, your're using identity columns. unless you partitioned your identity values (client 1 is 1-1000, client 2 is 1001 - 2000, etc...) you will duplicate IDs when you upload them.

have a look at this: [Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)